# How to display async data in vue template

Tags: javascript, templates, asynchronous, vue.js

I'm interesting in the case of displaying in vue template data which loaded asynchroniously. In my particular situation I need to show title attribute of product object:

```
<td class="deals__cell deals__cell_title">{{ getProduct(deal.metal).title }}</td>
```

But the product isn't currently loaded so that the title isn't rendered at all. I found a working solution: if the products aren't loaded then recall getProduct function after the promise will be resolved:

```
getProduct (id) {
  if (!this.rolledMetal.all.length) {
    this.getRolledMetal()
      .then(() => {
        this.getProduct(id)
      })
    return {
      title: ''
    }
  } else {
      return this.getRolledMetalById(id)
  }
}
```

However maybe you know more elegant solution because I think this one is a little bit sophisticated :)

Answer (score 36):

> I always use a loader or a spinner when data is loading!

```html
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>One</th>
        <th>Two</th>
        <th>Three</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      <template v-if="loading">
        <spinner></spinner> <!-- here use a loaded you prefer -->
      </template>

      <template v-else>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
          <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.lastName }}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
```

*And the script:*

```html
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        loading: false,
        rows: []
      }
    },
    created() {
      this.getDataFromApi()
    },
    methods: {
      getDataFromApi() {
        this.loading = true
        axios.get('/youApiUrl')
        .then(response => {
          this.loading = false
          this.rows = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
          this.loading = false
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: what happend if the getDataFromApi function is async ? does it make any difference?

Comment: @KickButtowski nah it can be async and everything will work fine. You just have to use await in the axios call + you can get rid of .then & .catch

Answer (score 8):

There are a few good methods of handling async data in Vue.

1. Call a method that fetches the data in the created lifecycle hook that assigns it to a data property. This means that your component has a method for fetching the data and a data property for storing it.
2. Dispatch a Vuex action that fetches the data. The component has a computed property that gets the data from Vuex. This means that the function for fetching the data is in Vuex and your component has a computed property for accessing it.

In this case, it looks like your component needs to have a RolledMetal and based on that it retrieves a product. To solve this you can add methods that fetch both of them, and call them on the created lifecycle. The second method should be called in a then-block after the first one to ensure it works as expected.