# Vue / Router: How do I correctly fetch data before rendering page content?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt with Vue Router and Axios. I see Vue Router has this fantastic feature called [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards).

Unfortunately, in the example below, my `beforeRouteEnter()` function is called but seems to exit and switch pages before my manual `next()` method is called in `fetchPageData(next)`.

What is the correct pattern here?

```
export default {
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
        next(vm => {
            vm.fetchPageData(next);
        });
    },
    methods: {
        async fetchPageData(next) {
            const result = await this.$axios.$get('/api/v2/inventory/3906?apiKey=f54761e0-673e-4baf-86c1-0b85a6c8c118');
            this.$store.commit('property/setProperty', result[0]);
            next();
        }
    }
}
```

I assume that my first call to `next(vm => {})` is running asynchronously, allowing execution to continue, resulting in a page change before I (most likely incorrectly) try to callback next().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right, calling `next()` second time is incorrect. Your first call to `next()` tells Router "go on, you can proceed with changing active component (create/mount/render) and when the component is created, call my callback (passed as an argument to `next()`)

You can follow guidance in [Data fetching - fetching before navigation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation) Docs ie. fetching data first and call `next()` after but that requires to extract fetch logic from the component itself.

Generally I find easier to write all component in the way assuming data are not here on 1st render and are coming later when all async calls resolve...

**UPDATE** Nuxt async data fetching options

As you are using Nuxt.js you have some other options how to use async data:

1. [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store#the-nuxtserverinit-action) - useful to fill client-side Vuex store with data from server side
2. [fetch method](https://nuxtjs.org/api/pages-fetch#the-fetch-method) - The fetch method is used to fill the store before rendering the page. It's like the `asyncData` method except it doesn't set the component data and allows you to put the data into the store. Returning Promise from `fetch` method will make Nuxt wait for promise to resolve before it renders the component...
3. [asyncData](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data#the-asyncdata-method) method can be used to to fetch data and put it inside component's `data`. Returning Promise from `asyncData` method will make Nuxt wait for promise to resolve before it renders the component...

```js
export default {
  async fetch({store, $axios}) {
    const result = await $axios.$get('/api/v2/inventory/3906');
    store.commit('property/setProperty', result[0]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly the asyncData isn't working for me as I need to put the data in a store and I can't seem to access the store from within it. Can you please post an example of how to use next() with "extracting fetch logic from the component itself" as you mentioned.

Comment: Added more Nuxt specific options of how to do async data. If you are using a store, use `fetch` instead of `asyncData`....

Answer (score 6):

> **What is happening there, is that you already calling `next` and that's**
>   **why the route enters immediately.**

Where you are calling next ?

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {  // <= HERE you execute next
        vm.fetchPageData(next);
    });
},
```

And the above code will execute `vm.fetchPageData` when the component is already rendered.

So even if you don't call `next` on the `fetchPageData` the route will enter.

---

By assuming that you want to enter the view after certain data is fetched by BE you can use `beforeEnter` on the router config:

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/foo',
      component: Foo,
      beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        axios.get('api/...')
          .then(response => {
             store.commit('mutation', response)
             next()
          })
          .catch(e => {
            alert('Something went wrong')
            next(false)
          })
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

Another solution would be to allow the route to enter but show a loader while data is being fetched: [Checkout this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49746754/6385184)

Comment: Can you please suggest a way that I could achieve my goal (first load data, then switch pages) from within the component (from readability perspective - as opposed to in the router configuration)? I'm not sure how to access the vm (to get access to $axios) without using next function, which is then called too early.

Comment: As far as I can see you are using an axios instance. So you can import this instance and use the axios in the router config. In that case you will not need to use `this` (Vue instance)

Comment: If you still can't find a solution, ping me on rolanddoda2014@gmail.com and I will make a simple demo for you