# Vue getter and setting return promise value if value is set

Tags: vue.js, promise

Hey I want to use a getter and setting computed property, just to make setting a value easy and then returning enriched data when it has been set.

So i'm setting the value, and then when fetching it hitting an API which will return the data, however `Promise` is being returned when the value is `null` on initial load of the component.

```js
computed: {
    troubleshooting: {
        async get() {
            if (!this.troubleshootingValue) {
                return null;
            }
            return (await Axios.post('/api/troubleshoot', this.troubleshootingValue)).data;
        },
        set(value) {
            this.troubleshootingValue = value;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Any idea why the initial `if` isn't being hit and return `null`?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right approach, although if hit your if condition and return null what you are returning by calling an asynchronous function is still a promise.

Answer (score 0):

[`async` functions *always* return Promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#return_value) Your `if` *is* being hit and returning `null`, but the `async` means that the value returned is a Promise that resolves to `null`. If you want to be able to return a raw `null` value instead of a Promise, the function can't be `async`.

(Why? You could imagine an `await` call happening before your `if`, which means that the `null` return value isn't known until the awaited promise resolves. You aren't using that capability here, but `async` allows it, and it doesn't make sense to have `async` have different behavior depending on the body of your function.)

This might not actually be a problem: Your implementation in the question has the nice predictable behavior of *always* returning a Promise, so callers don't need to check the return value to figure out whether it should behave like a Promise. In contrast, if you can sometimes synchronously return `null`, callers might require an `if` check or `Promise.resolve()` wrapper.

That said, for an alternative that synchronously returns `null`, you can either delegate to an `async` function to keep using `await`:

```js
/* not async */ get() {
    if (!this.troubleshootingValue) {
        return null;
    }
    return (async () => (
        await Axios.post('/api/troubleshoot', this.troubleshootingValue)).data
    )();
}
```

Or just manually chain `then`:

```
/* not async */ get() {
    if (!this.troubleshootingValue) {
        return null;
    }
    return Axios.post('/api/troubleshoot', this.troubleshootingValue))
        .then(x => x.data);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately, the data remains a `Promise` even after it was completed.

Comment: @MartynBall I've tested it here: https://jsfiddle.net/gjdfxkmh/3/ Note that in the Q component (yours), the first value is a **Promise of `null` until the value is set**; in A1 and A2 (my first and second answers) the value is a **raw `null` until the value is set**. I've also added the `promiseWatcher` machinery into the link, because without additional plugins Vue has never been good about [displaying asynchronous data in templates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49745497/1426891). If you're still having trouble, please post a reproducible example here or in your question.